# Clash of clans. Can I use my wife's Game Center account on my phone to start a new village?

Tags: iphone

Am I able to log in under my wife's games center account on my phone, without loosing my current village under my Game Center account? When I logged in under her Game Center account and began to open clash of clans, it said the current village would be deleted... So I cancelled. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you can only start a new game on any new device where the game has never been played on previously.

Source: [Supercell Game Support](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/201748676-How-can-I-reset-my-village-)